# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection(id:0)

Tags: react-native

I meet something strange and found no answer.
I met the warning as below:

`Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection(id:0)
 TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '_api2.default.getResp(URL, "GET")'....`

Below is shortened code like what my source code is.
The "Pass Code" works fine and "Warning Code" shows warning as above.

Why **Api.getResp** goes wrong but **Api.loggedin.getResp** works OK? They are so similar!!

**Warning Code**

```
const GetData = {
  async fetchFeed() {
    console.log(`Api = ${Api}`); // Api = [Object Object]
    console.log(`Api.getResp = ${Api.getResp}`); // Api.getRest = undefined
    const { success, content } = await Api.getResp(`${URL}`, 'GET');
    if (success) {
        .....
    }
  },
};
module.exports = FetchApi;
```

**Pass Code**

```js
const GetData2 = {
  async syncData(): void {
      const { success, content } = await Api.loggedin.getResp(`${URL}`, 'GET');
      .....
  }
}
```

**API**

```js
const Api = {
  async getResp(url: string, method: string): Object {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url,
        { method,
          null,
          { 'content-type' : 'application/json' },
        });

      ......

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`fetch url: ${url}, error: ${error}`);
    }
    return result;
  },

  loggedin: {
    async getResp(url: string, method: string): Object {
      const accessToken = await this._getAccessToken();
      ....
      return result;
    },
  },
```

Comment: How do you import/export the Api module?

Comment: import Api from '../../utils/api';